# Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one (when linking with a .a containing a MachO64 object file on Linux)

Tags: c, linux, assembly, static-libraries, unix-ar

I tried to create a library and test it, but an error occurred.
error code:

```
./libasm.a: error adding symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I compiled it like this.
`nasm -f macho64 ft_strlen.s -o ft_strlen.o`
`ar rcs libasm.a ft_strlen.o`
`ranlib libasm.a`
`gcc main.c libasm.a`
Below is the source file

```
;ft_strlen.s
segment .text
    global ft_strlen

ft_strlen:
    mov     rax, 0
    jmp     count

count:
    cmp     BYTE [rdi + rax], 0
    je      exit
    inc     rax
    jmp     count

exit:
    ret
```

```c
/*main.c*/
#include <stdio.h>

int ft_strlen(char *str);

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "hello world";
    printf("%d \n", ft_strlen(str));
}
```

I am using ubuntu installed on wsl.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `macho64` is for MacOS.  Use `-f elf64` for Linux (including on WSL).  Not sure if that's your only problem or not; most people don't add their `.o` files to static libraries, they just link them normally like `gcc -fno-pie -no-pie -g  main.c ft_strlen.o`.

Comment: code review: Use `.s` for files that GAS can assemble, like `gcc -S` output.  Use `.asm` for NASM source (which you *can't* run GCC on directly).  Also, `jmp count` is pointless - execution will fall through into the loop without a `jmp`.  You could rotate your loop to put the conditional branch at the bottom like normal idiomatic assembly code, then `jmp` to that branch condition to start the loop with the check before the increment.  Or just start with `rax=-1` and let the first increment run to make it `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate object files for Linux-based operating system (or perhaps more correctly, and ELF64 system) with `nasm -f elf64 ft_strlen.s -o ft_strlen.o`

For more info `nasm -hf` to see all valid output formats for `nasm -f`

Small tip: `ranlib` command is not needed because `ar s` is already indexing the library.